# Spring Security exclude url

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

I added two filter like below

1. JwtUsernameAndPasswordAuthenticationFilter
2. JwtTokenVerifier

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{
     @Override
     protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
 
      http
        .csrf().disable()
        .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
        .and()
        .authorizeRequests() 
            .antMatchers("/makestory").hasAnyRole("OLDBIE")
           
        .and()
            .addFilter(new JwtUsernameAndPasswordAuthenticationFilter()) 
            .addFilterAfter(new JwtTokenVerifier(), JwtUsernameAndPasswordAuthenticationFilter.class) 
            .authorizeRequests()
        .anyRequest()
        .authenticated()
        .and()
            .exceptionHandling()
            .authenticationEntryPoint(new LoginErroHandler());

}
```

and but I want to exclude some of urls like /main/, /main/story/, etc

so I was expected that /main/, /main/story/ urls don't need to be censored

so I added below code

```
@Override
public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
    web
        .ignoring()
        .antMatchers("/main/**");  
        
}
```

but there's a problem. A request has been passed to JwtUsernameAndPasswordAuthenticationFilter class

```
public class JwtUsernameAndPasswordAuthenticationFilter extends UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter {
   
    @Override
    public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws AuthenticationException{
            log.info("JwtUsernameAndPasswordAuthenticationFilter is actived");
    }
}
```

I don't want to a request be passed into JwtUsernameAndPasswordAuthenticationFilter

what should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update:

_____ Only to bypass Security _____

You may add matchers and permit before asking authentication for any other request

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter
{
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception
    { 
        http
         .
         .
         .
        .antMatchers("/main/**")
        .permitAll()
        .anyRequest()
        .authenticated()
         .
         .
}
```

this part may not be necessary only for bypass auth.

```
public void configure(WebSecurity web)
```

______ apply filter to only matching _______

```
    @Bean
    public FilterRegistrationBean<JwtUsernameAndPasswordAuthenticationFilter> loggingFilter() {
        FilterRegistrationBean<JwtUsernameAndPasswordAuthenticationFilter> registrationBean = new FilterRegistrationBean<>();

        registrationBean.setFilter(new JwtUsernameAndPasswordAuthenticationFilter());
        registrationBean.addUrlPatterns("/home**", "/test", "/sample/**");

        return registrationBean;
    }
```

Comment: Sorry, what i said only bypass security features, not the filters. There is a method but not by ignoring but adding filters to only matches. follow : https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-add-filter